# $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is a group under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

> Show that the set $$ \mathbb{Z}^*_p=\{1,2, \dots, p-1\} $$ where $p
>  \in \mathbb{N}$ is prime, is a **group** under multiplication.

**Attempt:**

*Associativity and identity:*

Obviously, multiplication $\bmod p$ is associative and $1 \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$ (identity element).

*Inverses:*

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$. Since $k<p$, $\gcd(k,p)=1$ and therefore Bezout's Lemma ensures that there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$
ak+bp=1\iff ak+bp \equiv 1 \space\bmod p \iff ak \equiv1 \bmod p
$$

However, is the fact $a<p$ guaranteed, so that $a=k^{-1}\in \mathbb{Z}^*_p?$

Is it because the congruence class $\bar{a}$ with $a<p$ contains every $a_i$ you choose s.t.
$
a_ik \equiv 1 \bmod p
$?

Comment: I think you're mixing up integers and classes of integers modulo $p$.

Comment: If that $a\in \Bbb Z$ is not in the list of the explicitly declared representatives, choose the one representative which is $a$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @Junkyards So, it would make more sense to work with classes: since there exists $a \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$
a \bar{k} \equiv 1 \bmod p
$$
the inverses exist?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the idea behind reasoning modulo $p$

Comment: If you show that if $gcd(a,p)=1$ and $gcd(b,p)=1$ than $gcd(a \cdot b,p)=1$ you are done, are'nt you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing up integers and classes of integers modulo $p$. The set you just gave should not be set of integers, but a set of classes of integers modulo $p$. Indeed, it if was a set of integers, it would not be a group : $(p-1) \times 2$ is not in this set !

But if you consider these elements as classes of integers modulo $p$, then all of your reasoning makes sense, and the element $a$ you get is indeed the inverse you are looking for : it's a class of integers. It just turns out that there is a representative of it between $1$ and $p-1$.